# .htaccess redirect wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress setup that I am going to host a payment portal on now

I just want to redirect all the urls that contain the word training

I have these rules in my .htaccess file but they dont work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} training
RewriteRule https://{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Just to be clear not query string parameters. But a part of the url 
e.g.

`www.abc.com/training/ should got to https://www.abc.com/training/`

`www.abc.com/training/test123/ should got to https://www.abc.com/trainig/test123/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `%` before `{HTTP_HOST}`, it will be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^training/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} training [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?(.*)$ https://$1 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, this world is far not perfect, and there is no reliable online-testing tool for mod_rewrite, so the last line could possibly be different:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: will test and let u know in sometime